# Map not showing up when reopening file

Tags: qgis

I know this question has been asked before but none of the solutions seem to be working for me.  Every-time I reopen a print composer map nothing shows up.  I have the map on render so that's not the problem and I played with CRS setting but nothing changed.  I have to recreate the map everytime I reopen the print composer which is annoying.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you click update preview? What do you mean by "I have to redraw the map"?

Comment: Yea I have updated preview.

Comment: Is the original print composer map item *missing*, or blank?

Comment: Blank...it appears that when I reopen the layout the "extents" are changed.  The "X min" and "X max" are changing each time I open the file.